# How to stop percent encoding in HTML form submission

Tags: html, forms, amazon-web-services, get

I am trying to give users of my website the ability to download files from Amazon S3. The URLs are digitally signed by my AWS private key on my webserver than sent to the client via AJAX and embedded in the action attribute of an html form.

The problem arises when the form is submitted. The action attribute of the form contains a url that has a digital signature. This signature often times contains `+` symbols which get percent-encoded. It completely invalidates the signature. How can I keep forms from percent-encoding my urls?

Comment: Your can use a shorten URL service

Comment: @Guy: How would that keep the URL from being percent encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (respectfully) suggest that you need to more carefully identify the precise nature of the problem, where in the process flow it breaks down, and identify precisely what it is that you actually need to fix.  URLEncoding of "+" is the correct thing for the browser to do, because the literal "+" in a query string is correctly interpreted by the server as " " (space).

Your question prompted me to review code I've written that generates signed urls for S3 and my recollection was correct -- I'm changing '+' to %2B, '=' to %3D, and '/' to %2F in the signature... so that is not invalid.  This is assuming we are talking about the same thing, such that the "digital signature" you mention in the question is the signature discussed here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth

Note the signature in the example has a urlencoded '+' in it: Signature=vjbyPxybdZaNmGa**%2B**yT272YEAiv4%3D

I will speculate that the problem you are having might not be '+' → '%2B' (which should be not only valid, but required)... but perhaps it's a double-encoding, such that you are, at some point, double-encoding it so that '+' → '%2B' → '%252B' ... with the percent sign being encoded as a literal, which would break the signature.

Comment: If I could reach through the screen and shake your hand I would. Let me start by saying that this was strange because the URLs would work when the signature contained no reserved characters like '+' etc. The '='s character is reserved but I was manually append a '%3D' (not knowing how to URL encode the base64 encoded string). So uploads would work 50% of the time. What I've done now is call èncodeURIComponent()`in javascript on the signature portion of the URL and things have worked exactly as you have stated above. I'd give you +2 if I could.

Comment: Now, getting the downloads to work is a whole different story. AJAX uploading binary data is very nice. Too bad we can't save files through AJAX downloads. I'm appending the temp URL to a form. Was wondering if you've had experience w/ sending temporary download URLs that are appended to forms and then submitted by the user. Figure it couldn't hurt in asking ;)

Comment: That's sort of a separate question, but I send authorized users to protected S3 downloads with a redirect.  The link the user actually clicks points to my server, which, after verifying that the download is authorized for that particular user (since it's a link back to me, the cookies are all there), returns a "302 Found" redirect response, with a quickly-expiring signed S3 URL in the "Location:" header, which causes the browser to go fetch the file from S3 but not to remember the redirect for next time, since it will have expired.

Comment: Note also that you don't want a mechanism like this to be usable by a malicious user to discover anything about your system, so, in the interest of not showing my cards, my system responds to any unauthorized or invalid or unexpected request with a 404, and validates your session and does other "technically unnecessary" things prior to returning the error, so that there's no opportunity to distinguish between "it's really not here" and "you aren't allowed to see it"  based on measuring differences in the server's response times.

Comment: I suppose the security measure I am taking is the fact that users have to be logged in and have a credit card to upload / download anything. URLs are only sent if you have a valid session. I like your idea of redirecting the user, my only concern is streaming data from the server to client. The files I'm working with can be large and that could become a significant bottleneck. I'd rather have them just download straight from amazon. The problem with downloading files from an HTML form is that you have no access over the headers that are sent, so the signature won't match. AJAX isn't an option.

Comment: Uh... "redirect" doesn't stream data to the client.  After my server verifies that the request is legit, I build and sign an S3 url in response to the request, and the 302 causes the user's browser to fetch the file directly from S3 with the signed url, not through me.  For downloads, using query string authentication, the headers sent by the browser aren't inspected by S3. Only the path has to match, and the signature has to not be expired.

Comment: I'm sorry I gave the impression that "redirect" means "streaming data to the client". That was not my intention. In the last paragraph you wrote, you made it sound like you were downloading files from amazon to the client by way of your webserver. Which is not an option for me. Sorry for the confusion. I now see that your redirect allows the user to download from S3 directly. Thanks for your help and wish me luck.

Comment: Your redirect trick worked. Thanks again! Do you save your objects with file extensions? If not, do you know how to change the file extension upon download?